# Kafka's server.properties file under Cloudera's manager?

Tags: apache-kafka, cloudera

Where is the kafka's server.properties file if it's been managed by cloudera's manager?

Answer (score 1):

It will be under `/opt/cloudera/parcels/KAFKA-2.0.0-1.kafka2.0.0.p0.12/etc/kafka/conf.dist/server.properties`

Answer (score 0):

i Personally would suggest to `locate server.properties` if you use ubuntu. My kafka was installed via ambari and it was located at /etc/kafka/3.1.4.0-315/0/server.properties